# Problems with string selection with re in python

Tags: python, regex

I'm doing an exercise in Python, and I'm stuck at this part where I have to detect dates in a string using re.

My only problem is that I when the day is "1st", it outputs a blank string. What am I doing wrong?

```
import re
text = "article 1st May 1988; another article 2 June 1992, some new article 25 October 2001; "

result = re.findall(r'(\d*) ([A-Z]\w+) (\d+)',text)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[('', 'May', '1988'), ('2', 'June', '1992'), ('25', 'October', '2001')]
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: The `st` isn't matched by anything. Note that `[A-Z]` doesn't match a space, and `\d*` will also match 0 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could force at least one number (with `\d+` instead of just `\d*`) and add a subset of possible strings for ordinals :

```
import re
text = "article 1st May 1988; another article 2 June 1992, some new article 25 October 2001; "

result = re.findall(r'(\d+(?:st|nd|rd|th)?) ([A-Z]\w+) (\d+)',text)
print(result)
# [('1st', 'May', '1988'), ('2', 'June', '1992'), ('25', 'October', '2001')]
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

`\d*` matches zero or more occurrences of a digit followed by a space. In '1st' however a digit is followed by 's'.

It's questionable whether `\d*` is at all the right thing to match. You probably want one or more digits. Or better even limit that to at most two digits (e.g. `\d{1,2}`) optionally followed by 'st', 'nd', 'rd' or 'th'.